# Recursive items in JSON schema

Tags: recursion, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm designing a JSON schema with a recursive element. This element is not at the root, but in a subschema:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "http://example.org/json-schema/struct.schema.json",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "title": "Structure",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "title": "ID",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "label": {
                "title": "Label",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "children": {
                "$anchor": "children",
                "title": "Children",
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "title": "Structure Item",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "title": "ID",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "href": {
                            "title": "Reference",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "label": {
                            "title": "Structure Item Label",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "sort_label": {
                            "title": "Sort Label",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "children": {"$ref": "children"}
                    }
                },
                "anyOf": [
                    {"required": ["id", "href"]},
                    {"required": ["id", "children"]}
                ]
            }
        },
        "required": ["id", "label", "children"]
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the schema, I either get an error (with an online validator), or get caught in a loop (wit `python-fastjsonschema`), due to the recursion in `items.properties.children`.

From the examples in https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring#recursion it is not clear to me what is allowed for recursion and what is not. Recursive `$ref`s inside `$def`s are not allowed, but `$ref`s to the root anchor are listed in a valid example. They all create a loop (that is indeed the purpose of recursion!). I thought that `$ref` to a non-root anchor would be OK but it's clearly not.

I also tried to use a non-named anchor as in `"children": {"$ref": "#/items/properties/children"}`, and the schema compiles, but throws an error on validation.

How shall I model this schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the anchor with a `#` symbol.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "http://example.org/json-schema/struct.schema.json",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "title": "Structure",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "title": "ID",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "label": {
                "title": "Label",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "children": {
                "$anchor": "children",
                "title": "Children",
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "title": "Structure Item",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "title": "ID",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "href": {
                            "title": "Reference",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "label": {
                            "title": "Structure Item Label",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "sort_label": {
                            "title": "Sort Label",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "children": {"$ref": "#children"}
                    }
                },
                "anyOf": [
                    {"required": ["id", "href"]},
                    {"required": ["id", "children"]}
                ]
            }
        },
        "required": ["id", "label", "children"]
    }
}
```

This is a passing instance.

```json
[
    {
        "id": "",
        "label": "",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": "",
                "href": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

You may want to reconsider your `anyOf` required constraints because at the moment with `anyOf`, they are not really required in the way I think you want them required.  Try `oneOf`

Comment: Thanks, the anchor did it. That was a mistake on my end. However, as you mention, not all parsers like this setup. python-fastjsonschema gives me an error on compile. As to `anyOf`, I want the children to have `href`, or `children`, or both. Accoding to the [docs](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining) that's `anyOf` does. `oneOf` would allow only one of the two.

Comment: My comment about `anyOf` relates to the required properties are not required at all. It only states if they are present, they must be either of those defined schemas. The way it's written now allows the children schema to be empty  `"children":[]`

Comment: That's fine with me. I can have a "stub" container with no children and no href, but to indicate that it's a container, it has the mandatory children section empty.